# SQL query unique values based on 2 colums

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, common-table-expression, sql-view, ssms-2012

I need help figuring this out.

At the moment I have this query:

```
SELECT Table1.Column1 AS Company
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, Table2.Column2, Table1.Column3)) AS DiffDate
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Column6 = Table2.Column6
    AND Table1.Column5 = Table2.Column5
GROUP BY Company
```

The result of this is...

```
Company        DiffDate  

company1          8
```

But this is not what I want because there are values that are the combinations of column5 and column6 that are the same. See below.

```
Company  |  Column6  |  Column5  |  DiffDate  
Company1 |   5782    |     10    |      2  
Company1 |   5782    |     10    |      2  
Company1 |   5782    |     20    |      2  
Company1 |   5782    |     30    |      2
```

So the result I'm after is 6, not 8.

I tried using `SELECT DISTINCT` but that doesn't do anything.

Thank you in advance.

*edit 2016-02-09*

I've made the following query in SSMS.

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT bestlevdat, bestradnr, bestnr FROM dbo.bpa)
SELECT  dbo.bp.ftgnr AS Företagsnr,SUM(DATEDIFF(Day,cte.bestlevdat, dbo.bp.bestberlevdat)) AS Diff_Bekräftat_dat, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(Day,cte.bestlevdat, dbo.bp.bestbeglevdat)) AS Diff_Önskat_dat, COUNT(dbo.bp.bestradnr) AS AntalRader, SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day, cte.bestlevdat, dbo.bp.bestberlevdat) < - 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Antal_avvikande_rader, ROUND((COUNT(dbo.bp.bestradnr) - SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day, cte.bestlevdat, dbo.bp.bestberlevdat) < - 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)) * 100 / COUNT(dbo.bp.bestradnr), 1) AS Levsäk
FROM    dbo.bp INNER JOIN
        cte ON dbo.bp.bestnr = cte.bestnr AND dbo.bp.bestradnr = cte.bestradnr
WHERE     (YEAR(dbo.bp.bestberlevdat) = '2015')
GROUP BY dbo.bp.ftgnr
ORDER BY AntalRader DESC
```

This works a charm. But when I create a new view and paste this query there and try to save I get an error on the ";" again. If I remove ";" in SSMS I get error "The multi-part identifier "cte.bestlevdat" could not be bound" and also converts my query to the following:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT bestlevdat, bestradnr, bestnr
                         FROM         dbo.bpa AS bpa_1)
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.bp.ftgnr AS Företagsnr, SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, cte_1.bestlevdat, dbo.bp.bestberlevdat)) AS Diff_Bekräftat_dat, SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, 
                        cte_1.bestlevdat, dbo.bp.bestbeglevdat)) AS Diff_Önskat_dat, COUNT(dbo.bp.bestradnr) AS AntalRader, SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day, cte.bestlevdat, 
                        dbo.bp.bestberlevdat) < - 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Antal_avvikande_rader, ROUND((COUNT(dbo.bp.bestradnr) - SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day, cte.bestlevdat, 
                        dbo.bp.bestberlevdat) < - 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)) * 100 / COUNT(dbo.bp.bestradnr), 1) AS Levsäk
 FROM         dbo.bp INNER JOIN
                        cte AS cte_1 ON dbo.bp.bestnr = cte_1.bestnr AND dbo.bp.bestradnr = cte_1.bestradnr
 WHERE     (YEAR(dbo.bp.bestberlevdat) = '2015')
 GROUP BY dbo.bp.ftgnr
 ORDER BY AntalRader DESC
```

Sorry if I've missed something obvious, but I'm pretty new with querys and this is my first attempt on "View".

Comment: Sample data from both tables would help.

Comment: Why *don't* you want to count them? What if there *are* two such rows in Table 2? How do you decide that one is junk? Why don't you remove it from Table 2 then?

Comment: I'm creating statistics over delivery reliability. Column6 is order number, Column5 is Order row number. When order row number comes twice on the same order number then we've made 2 or more separate transactions on that row because of different circumstances. So I don't want to calculate with the same deviation twice.

Comment: Does anyone else know how I can solve this problem? Or maybe bump this thread up for others to see?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do something like you want the distinct rows from Table2, and to join/aggregate them from Table1, so using a CTE may help, so something like:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
                Column2,
                Column5,
                Column6
    FROM        Table2
)
SELECT
            Table1.Column1 AS Company, 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, cte.Column2, Table1.Column3)) AS DiffDate

FROM        Table1 

INNER JOIN  cte
    ON      Table1.Column6 = cte.Column6 
    AND     Table1.Column5 = cte.Column5

GROUP BY Company
```

Comment: Hi Rowland, This seems to do the trick although I don't really understand what it does (never seen "WITH cte AS" before). :) My problem is though, that it works in SQL server management studios but I use an addon in Excel that executes the query and posts the results in my list. My error message is: "Illegal character ; in query string". But I suppose it's hard to help me on this one so I'll have to try and figure it out myself.

Comment: The CTE (Commom Table Expression) effectively creates a view on the fly that be can used within the scope of the expression. The previous expression must be explicitly terminated (hence the `;`) to use CTEs. Alternately, you could create an actual view on your database that represents the data you're wanting to aggregate

Comment: I've edited my first post and would appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks in advance.